# Simplifying a system of linear inequalities

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

Given two inequalities

$y\geq m_1(x-x_1)+y_1$

and

$y\geq m_2(x-x_2)+y_2$

Is there anyway to solve for the space that they both exist in?

I tried setting them equal to each other but that only gives me one solution at the interception of their border lines.

Also sorry for the quality post I'm doing this from a phone.

Comment: You can find the feasible region graphically. Consider two cases: $m_1=m_2$ and $m_1\ne m_2$.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing it graphically and do it analytically, also what is special about the the to cases

Comment: The two lines are parallel or intersecting. Analytically, you will still have some inequality conditions indicated under a set notation.

Comment: Ok? That doesn't really help me, are you going yo just give me cryptic advice or something more solid.

Comment: Analyze the specific example:http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3E%3Dx%2C+y%3E%3D-x&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider two regions: $R_1=\{(x,y):y\ge a_1x+b_1\}$ and $R_2=\{(x,y):y\ge a_2x+b_2\}$. You are looking for $R = R_1 \cap R_2$. So, if $a_1 x+b_1 < a_2 x+ b_2$, then $\{(x,y):y\ge a_2 x+b_2\}$ lies in $R$; otherwise, $\{(x,y):y\ge a_1 x+b_1\}$ lies in $R$.

See the attached figure for an example.[image: A simple example.]

First, you need to compute the intersection point of two lines $y=a_1 x+b_1=a_2 x+ b_2$ ($(-4/3,2/3)$ in the figure). Afterwards, determine the range of $x$ when $a_1 x+b_1 < a_2 x+ b_2$. In the example, $x<-4/3$ for $a_1=1$, $b_1=4$, $a_2=-0.5$, and $b_2=2$. Then $$y \ge \left\{\begin{matrix}-0.5x+2 & \text{ if $x < -4/3$;}\\x+4 & \text{ if $x \ge -4/3$.}\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: In sorry this is still all going way over my head.

Comment: @AaronQuitta Hopefully, the edited post will help you understand.